# Template class buffer destructor c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, destructor

I have a template class Array that has a buffer type vector.

```
template <typename T>
    class Array
    {
    protected:
        std::vector<T> buffer; 
     ......
    }
```

I want to implement the destructor  `~Array();` for this buffer. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Is there something you need to do upon destruction that is not handled by the default destructor?

Comment: How to do what, exactly? What would you want your destructor to do?

Comment: A `std::vector` has a default destructor that takes care of releasing it's allocated memory.

Comment: I want to delete the allocated memory of the buffer

Answer (score 1):

The default destructor is already releasing the memory of vector, you don't need to define one here.

If you want to free memory of the vector explicitly, then try swap technique whenever you want:

```
std::vector<T>().swap(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas on how to do it?

It depends completely on what you've designed the class and its destructor to do.

The best option, when ever it does what is needed, is to not have a user declared destructor at all, but the implicitly generated one instead. In other words, follow the [rule of 0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) when possible.

> I want to delete the allocated memory of the buffer

All member variables are destroyed automatically. The destructor of the vector deallocates its internal buffer. There is no need for a custom destructor here.